# Converting text file to all uppercase letters

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, jgrasp

I have an assignment for class and I have to make a program that takes an existing file and converts all the letters to uppercase. Below is part of the code (specifically the loop):

```
 // Read lines from the file until no more are left.
  while (inputFile.hasNext())
  {
      // Read the next name.
     String friendName = inputFile.nextLine();

      // Need line to make all letters uppercase

  }

  System.out.print("Enter the saved file name: ");
  String filename2 = keyboard.nextLine();
```

When I run it now: I am able to open the first text file and a second txt file is created, but there is no letters in the new file.

Comment: See [`String` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 3):

You may try like this:

```
File file1 = new File("initial.txt");
File file2 = new File("final.txt"); 
char CharCounter = 0;       
BufferedReader in = (new BufferedReader(newFileReader(file1)));
PrintWriter out = (new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file2)));
int ch;
while ((ch = in.read()) != -1)
{
   if (Character.isLowerCase(ch))
   {
        ch=Character.toUpperCase(ch);// convert assign variable
   }
out.write(ch);
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

Comment: This code works to write into the new file, but the characters are still lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Try `String upper = friendName.toUpperCase()`.
Now the `upper` String has all the character in the uppercase.Use it according to your need. Refer [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: You might want to assign the result to `friendName`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [String class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and try to find a method to change the string value to all uppercase.

Also you need to get the output file name above the `while` loop and then write to the output file inside the loop since for every iteration of the loop, the string value of the previous iteration is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileUtils` [readFileToString()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29) and [writeFileToString()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to do the work simple,

```
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(FILE_PATH));
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(FILE_PATH), content.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
friendName = friendName +System.lineSeparator()+friendName.toUpperCase();
```

//After the while loop finishes, write the contents of friendName in your output file.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Demo Code:

```
       import java.io.*;
       import java.util.*;
       class m{

  public static void main (String[] args) {
     try
    {
     FileReader fr = new FileReader("file.java");
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
     PrintWriter out = (new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("mahesh.java")));
     String s="";
   while((s = br.readLine()) != null) 
   {
      out.write(s.toUpperCase()+"\n");
    }
  out.close();
  }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package WT_LAB_THIRTEEN;
import java.io.*;

public class StringsToUpperCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\Web Tech\\WT_LAB_THIRTEEN\\InputFile.txt")));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(
                new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Web Tech\\WT_LAB_THIRTEEN\\OutputFile.txt")));
        int ch;
        while ((ch = br.read()) != -1) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
                ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
            }
            /*the below part of the code can be used to convert UpperCase characters to lowerCase 
            else if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
                ch = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
            }*/
            pw.write(ch);
        }
        br.close();
        pw.close();
    }
}
```